# Change color of text and svg inside the div on hover/mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried to implement add/remove class for the text and it worked, but the issue is when the mouse out the transition is lost, how it can be keeped?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bookmark').mouseover(function() {
    $('#text').addClass('light-blue-link')
  });
  $('#bookmark').mouseout(function() {
    $('#text').removeClass('light-blue-link')
  });
});
```

```css
.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
  transition: color 1s ease;
}


.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bookmark' class='button'>
  <span id='text' class=''>Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not transitioning on `mouseout` because the `transition` property is removed when the class is removed. If you want the element to transition on `mouseover` and `mouseout`, the `transition` property should remain changed even if the class is removed, therefore you need to add the transition to the `#text` element directly (rather than the class that is added and then removed):

```js
$('#bookmark').mouseover(function() {
  $('#text').addClass('light-blue-link')
});
$('#bookmark').mouseout(function() {
  $('#text').removeClass('light-blue-link')
});
```

```css
#text {
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
.light-blue-link {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bookmark' class='button'>
  <span id='text'>Text</span>
</div>
```

As a side note, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you *may* not need jQuery:

```css
#text {
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
.button:hover #text {
  color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bookmark' class='button'>
  <span id='text'>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice no-jQuery solution.